Determine which dependency is causing vulnerable jackson-databind jar to be cached in maven repo
Currently getting a vulnerable version of jackson-databind showing up in maven cache of our dev machines/build server, and being flagged on a security scan.  By trial and error, I have found the project causing the vulnerable  jackson-databind to come down, but have not been able to determine why.

Running mvn dependency:tree does not show the jackson-databind version I'm trying to hunt down
Running mvn dependency:resolve-plugins seems to only show plugin direct dependencies and seeing no evidence of jackson-databind

Is there another command I can run to see ALL transitive dependencies application, plugin, etc?  I suspect it is something in the build process requiring it and I have not been able to pin it down.
Update: I ran the dependency tree with the -Dverbose.  This revealed a direct dependency calling for jackson-databind 2.9.2. Although it is omitted for a new version, it seems the 2.9.2 dependency is still downloaded into the maven cache.  Is there a way to prevent maven from downloading omitted dependencies?
Dependency graph below for problem dependency:
[INFO] +- com.duosecurity:duo-universal-sdk:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.14.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:jar:2.9.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.14.3)
[INFO] |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.14.3)
[INFO] |  +- com.auth0:java-jwt:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.14.3)
[INFO] |  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.9)
[INFO] |  \- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:jar:4.9.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:4.9.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.14.9)
[INFO] |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] |           \- (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.4.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)



You can use a Maven property: maven.repo.local.recordReverseTree it will generate reverse dependency tree in your local maven repository ~/.m2/repository
It is a startup property so, can not be used in project pom.xml, you can ues it:

on command line: mvn ... -Dmaven.repo.local.recordReverseTree
in project .mvn/maven.config
or in settings.xml in in profile/properties - https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#properties

Under each artifacts directory will be generated a .tracking directory which has contains information why this dependency was resolved.
Eg.
ls -1 ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/.tracking/
org.codehaus.mojo_taglist-maven-plugin_3.1.0.plugin
org.codehaus.mojo_taglist-maven-plugin_jar_3.1.0.dep

cat ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.7/.tracking/org.codehaus.mojo_taglist-maven-plugin_jar_3.1.0.dep 
org.apache.velocity:velocity:pom:1.7
  org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.11.1 (compile) (plugin)
    org.codehaus.mojo:taglist-maven-plugin:jar:3.1.0 () (plugin)

Repository: central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)


